# Unable to build substrate-node-template: parity-scale-codec version mismatch

Tags: substrate-node-template

I'm just following the basic steps from the [quickstart](https://docs.substrate.io/quick-start/) and am running into the following:

```
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `parity-scale-codec = "^3.0.0"`
  candidate versions found which didn't match: 3.1.5, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, ...
  location searched: crates.io index
  required by package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/xxx/Projects/dot/substrate-node-template/runtime)`
      ... which satisfies path dependency `wasm-project` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template-runtime-wasm v1.0.0 (/Users/xxx/Projects/dot/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime)`
```

I already [found out](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/reason-for-yanked-parity-scale-codec-versions-3-0-3-1-1) that this version seems to no longer exist. However, simply upgrading in the toml file to a newer version raises the same error. I tried deleting the Cargo.lock file as well.

I'm new to this, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: What specific version of the node template are you using? The tag associated with Polkadot is what you are after, 0.9.(something)  usually

Comment: I just checked out the `main` branch. But the `polkadot-v0.9.29` yields the same error.

Comment: Ok. I found out that I have to run `scripts/init.sh` that installs the nigthly build of rust and then it started to work (that should be in the docs, though). There was also something odd with my local rust env with i just installed again from scratch.